# Tensorflow for Node GPU doesn't release memory

Tags: node.js, gpu, tensorflow.js

Using @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu 3.0.0 and CUDA 10.0 on Ubuntu 20.04

```
// Prepares and returns 4GB data
async function prepareData () {
  return {
    inputs: inputTensor,
    outputs: outputTensor
  }
}

export async function train () {
  const { inputs, outputs } = await prepareData()
  const model = getModel()

  await model.fit(inputs, outputs, {
    validationSplit: 0.2,
    epochs: EPOCHS,
    shuffle: true
  })

  await model.save('file://model')
}
```

When calling the `train` method from somewhere else in my running Node process, 4GB of memory is allocated on the GPU, inspected with `nvidia-smi`. When the training ends, the memory is never released.

I have tried `tf.dispose()`, `tf.disposeVariables`, wrapping in `tf.engine().startScope()/endScope()`. The only thing that frees the memory is killing the containing Node process (which is not very practical since its a web server).

Is there any way to clear the allocated memory without killing the Node process?

Comment: Could you try to wrap the body of the `train` function inside `tf.tidy` ?

Comment: No changes, still 4GB memory used on the GPU after training

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, though not a super elegant one. I moved all my tensorflow functionality to python, and then just start the python process from node. The memory is release when the process stops. I think the issue is that doing it in the same node process, the process never stops, and the memory never gets released. At least I find that tensorflow is easier to work with in python anyway.